# Submitting javascript form but data not passing correctly

Tags: javascript, forms, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass values by submitting a form but when it submitting I cant see any data passing on URL. it was confirmed by a LOGGER.

JavaScript code

function validateSelectedCombination() {

```
var program_Id = document.getElementById('id_select_program').value;


alert(program_Id);
document.getElementById('id_select_program').value;
document.getElementById("programFormDropDown").action=("../hDashBoard/project");
document.getElementById("programFormDropDown").submit();
```

}

form in JSP file

```
<form id="programFormDropDown">
    <label>Program :</label>    
    <select id="id_select_program" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title='Choose Program...'>            
          <c:forEach var="program" items="${programs}">
            <option  value="${program.programId}">${program.programName}</option>
        </c:forEach>            
    </select> 

    <input type="button" onclick="validateSelectedCombination()" value="Submit">
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/project" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView programValidate(HttpServletRequest request , ServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    String programId = request.getParameter("id_select_program");
    LOGGER.info("Selected program id" + programId);
    ModelAndView fileConfigModelView = new ModelAndView("fileUpload");
    return fileConfigModelView;
}
```

Comment: don't you need `name` attributes for your inputs/selects?

Comment: I can,t understand the purpose of name you mentioned??

Comment: You need `name` attributes to read the values when you send the form. ID's identify nodes on a document, not POST/GET variables. You need names for that =) try adding `name="id_select_program"` to your select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only field with a name attribute can be submitted, add name attribute to your select like this:
`<select name = "id_select_program"`

Comment: I mean the second one, the jsp file